# Error while calling an oracle procedure from liquibase changelog

Tags: liquibase

I have a procedure L_GRANT created in DB as given below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE L_GRANT (P_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT ON ' || P_TABLE_NAME || ' TO <USERSCHEMANAME>';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || P_TABLE_NAME || ' TO <VIEWSCHEMANAME>
END;
```

The same im trying to call from liquibase changelog like the below and getting error for the same.

```
<changeSet author="name" id="id1" dbms="oracle"> <sql> EXEC L_GRANT('DUMMY_TABLE') </sql> </changeSet>
```

ERROR

---

```
 Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
 [Failed SQL: EXEC L_GRANT('DUMMY_TABLE')]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:619)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1130)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:188)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:103)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Please suggest on what I'm missing in here...

Comment: try `execute` instead of `exec`

Comment: execute was also failing. tried with CALL statement last and that one is working now.

Answer (score 0):

CALL is working instead of EXEC statement.